# Using ArrayRef for random array item in perl

Tags: perl

The following example works as expected.

```
use 5.014;
use warnings;

package My::Items {
        use Moose;
        use Method::Signatures::Simple;

        has 'items' => ( is => 'rw', isa => 'ArrayRef[Str]',);

        method get_random {
                my @itm = @{$self->items};
                return undef unless( @itm );
                return $itm[ int(rand(@itm)) ];
        }
        __PACKAGE__->meta->make_immutable();
}

package main {
        my $items = My::Items->new(items => [qw(a b c d)]);
        say $items->get_random for(1..5);
}
```

The question is: How to rewrite the `get_random` method without using the helper array `@itm`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    method get_random {
            return unless @{$self->items};
            return $self->items->[ int(rand(@{$self->items})) ];
    }
```

or if you don't mind using references,

```
    method get_random {
            my $itm = $self->items;
            return unless @$itm;
            return $itm->[ int(rand(@$itm)) ];
    }
```

Comment: ok, thx - and what one is "prefered" from the "good practice" point of view? Using the helper arrayref variable `$itm` or the 1st variant?

Comment: @kobame helper variable adds to readability, and array reference doesn't copy array elements into new array, unlike `my @itm = @{$self->items};`